# .NET Compact Framework Component Serializer

Tags: .net, compact-framework, controls

I am porting .NET Framework component to .NET Compact Framework. Component has ImageList in it. This component implements custom CodeDomSerializer. The constructor of the custom CodeDomSerializer contains following code for ImageList code serialization.

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(ImageList), new DesignerSerializerAttribute(typeof(MyComponentCodeDomSerializer), typeof(CodeDomSerializer)));
```

But due to some reason, .NET Compact Framework doesn't use custom ImageList CodeDomSerializer (It works in .NET Framework.) It uses default CodeDomSerializer. Any ideas how can I attach ImageList custom CodeDomSerializer?

Comment: Custom CodeDomSerializer creates an instance of itself and adds attributes to TypeDescriptor. But it doesn't use DesignerSerializer (MyComponentCodeDomSerializer) to serializer ImageList. Compact Framework uses default serializer for ImageList. I am not able to figure out why designer doesn't use MyComponentCodeDomSerializer.

Comment: I am up-voting this because it shows how much I still need to learn about .NET CF

Answer (score 1):

I found out that there is so many differences between CF and WF designers, that it is impossible to save the same form on both designers. Most funny thing is, that if a form is not opened using a *platform* designer, it can be build anyway. So I have 2 projects,one for win, one for CE, default project is *win* and forms are designed using CE designer. Strange, but it works...

Answer (score 0):

The Compact Framework does not support the CodeDomSerializer class, so therefore your code is not working.
What are you trying to achieve with the custom CodeDomSerializer?

Comment: I am trying to use CodeDomSerializer class for .NET Compact Framework component designer. My component contains multiple image lists. When you add a component to .NET Compact Framework form, it gives an option to select image list. I want to change the default code serialization on form for an image list. Do you think it is possible in .NET Compact Framework?

Answer (score 0):

As I know Compact Framework doesn't support CodeDomSerializer, there even no appropriate Type or library. How can I treat Visual Studio designer and make it use my custom CodeDomSerializer?